# Plot border gets behind sf element in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a basic plot:

```
pb %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = couv_rappel)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "red", size = 2),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Plot1]

Now, if I restrain the plot with limits, I have:

```
pb %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = couv_rappel)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "red", size = 2),
        legend.position = "none") +
  xlim(2.3,2.4)
```

[image: Plot2]

As you can see, the plot left and right borders get behind the plotted object. Does anyone have a solution to get the border above the plot elements?

Thanks!

Data used:

```
pb <- structure(list(dep = "75", couv_rappel = 57.3, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(list(structure(c(2.46724637546176, 2.46575592250353, 
    2.46120600898013, 2.43669006552864, 2.42985496603744, 2.4199582646563, 
    2.4032827566051, 2.39006934685366, 2.36420634490071, 2.35635437759204, 
    2.3528666667096, 2.34390883177532, 2.33190823942743, 2.31414902154357, 
    2.30132131510763, 2.28939887025059, 2.28085866249027, 2.27192797978477, 
    2.2676168439641, 2.26278403146322, 2.2535603968777, 2.24805520435306, 
    2.22422447830154, 2.22566318222318, 2.23173608410806, 2.24569866927731, 
    2.25528620843296, 2.25997554492291, 2.27994638125302, 2.28445806712108, 
    2.30377644516541, 2.31988421733846, 2.32998322451236, 2.35187284606698, 
    2.3658401097796, 2.37028625603703, 2.38944370936257, 2.39650003656717, 
    2.39863816549655, 2.4003389935185, 2.41069370568239, 2.413263340928, 
    2.41531944369422, 2.41634007356596, 2.41597350659806, 2.41365345988931, 
    2.41652928944455, 2.42307640181955, 2.42757060634054, 2.44785155779452, 
    2.46724637546176, 48.839079305745, 48.8262836552197, 48.8183579113295, 
    48.8185510543002, 48.8233933012562, 48.8240824636363, 48.8292444489485, 
    48.825697080461, 48.8163977497727, 48.8159598008205, 48.818216578285, 
    48.8157574531834, 48.8170124945509, 48.8222907392244, 48.8251298670846, 
    48.8283515995125, 48.8313312729353, 48.8288853042635, 48.8342010419919, 
    48.8339284802732, 48.8368570967459, 48.8463198681933, 48.8535158838331, 
    48.8594069515364, 48.8690697019275, 48.8764605941563, 48.8743532798546, 
    48.8801925532761, 48.8785786260854, 48.8856382772024, 48.8941520304135, 
    48.9004587194173, 48.9011635770595, 48.9015268868537, 48.901610825998, 
    48.9016516431006, 48.901156965113, 48.8961929113555, 48.8894140761193, 
    48.8837472239427, 48.8784752787775, 48.8731186017642, 48.8551777489297, 
    48.8492377880662, 48.8466288464984, 48.8372275617342, 48.8346874842976, 
    48.8427061233008, 48.8415756560415, 48.8448097861725, 48.839079305745
    ), .Dim = c(51L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 2.22422447830154, 
ymin = 48.8157574531834, xmax = 2.46724637546176, ymax = 48.9016516431006
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"data.table", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(dep = NA_integer_, 
couv_rappel = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have used `plot.background`, which is drawn before the geom, rather than `panel.border`, which is drawn after. Try:

```
pb %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = couv_rappel)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "red", fill=NA, size = 2),
        legend.position = "none") +
  xlim(2.3,2.4)
```

[image]